# Calculate the height at which the two balls meet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

A ball is projected vertically upwards with a velocity of $20ms^{-1}$. Two seconds later, a second ball is projected vertically upwards with a velocity of $16ms^{-1}$. Find the height above the surface at which the two balls meet.

My attempt:

Set upward as positive. So we have $a = -g = -9.81ms^{-2}.$ $u_1=20ms^{-1}$, $u_2=16ms^{-1}$.

By using $s = ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2,$ I have $s_1 = 20t-4.905t^2$ and $s_2 = 16(t+2)-4.905(t+2)^2$.

When the two balls meet, we have $s_1=s_2.$ By solving the equation, I have $t = -0.524s$. Therefore, the height where the two balls meet is $s= 9.133s$, which is not the same as answer given $(s = 12.524)$

I do not know where is my mistake in my working.

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Your velocities have the wrong sign (if upwards is positive, $u_1 = 20 m/s$ and so on ...)